# Find one column value in other df and substitute by value in same row

Tags: r, tidy

I have 2 df's

Represents a serie of events

```
df1
| Event | 
|:----|
| AA | 
| AB | 
| AC  | 
| AD  | 
| AE  | 
| AE | 
| AD  | 
| AE | 
| AA  | 
| AE  | 
| AC  | 
| AD  | 
| AD  |
```

Represents the unique values of df1$Events with the factor number atributed.

```
df2
| Event | Factor | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| AA  | 1    | 
| AB  | 2    | 
| AC  | 3    | 
| AD | 4    | 
| AE  | 5    |
```

Expected output would be :

```
df1
| Event | 
| ----- | 
| 1  | 
| 2  |
| 3  | 
| 4  |
| 5  | 
| 5  | 
| 4  |
| 5  | 
| 1  |
| 5  | 
| 3  | 
| 4  |
| 4  |
```

Changing in df1 the events by the factor numbers created in df2.

I tried this nested for loop :

```
event_into_factor <- function(x,y,z) {
  len_x = nrow(x) 
  len_y = nrow(y)
  for (i in len_x){
    for (o in len_y){
      if(x[i] == y[o]){
        x[i] = z[o]
      }
    }
  }
}

event_into_factor(df1$Event,df2$Event, df2$Factor)
```

Anyone has a hint?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

We do the join and the `select` the 'Factor' column while renaming it

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'Event') %>% 
    select(Event = Factor)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match`. Since you have `Factor` values sequential i.e 1 to 5 `match` would directly return the index that you need

```
match(df1$Event, df2$Event)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 5 1 5 3 4 4
```

If the `Factor` values are different (like characters or numbers which are not sequential) you can use the index from `match` to get corresponding `Factor` value.

```
df2$Factor[match(df1$Event, df2$Event)]
```